# How to parse specific data of this JSON in .Net?

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc

This is my Json:

```
{
 "coord": {
  "lon": -0.13,
  "lat": 51.51
 },
 "weather": [{
  "id": 520,
  "main": "Rain",
  "description": "light intensity shower rain",
  "icon": "09d"
 }],
 "base": "stations",
 "main": {
  "temp": 289.42,
  "pressure": 1008,
  "humidity": 55,
  "temp_min": 287.15,
  "temp_max": 291.15
 },
 "visibility": 10000,
 "wind": {
  "speed": 4.1,
  "deg": 340
 },
 "rain": {
  "1h": 4.32
 },
 "clouds": {
  "all": 40
 },
 "dt": 1463937214,
 "sys": {
  "type": 1,
  "id": 5091,
  "message": 0.0474,
  "country": "GB",
  "sunrise": 1463889474,
  "sunset": 1463947050
 },
 "id": 2643743,
 "name": "London",
 "cod": 200
}
```

I want to deserialize this into a weather report class. I am interested only in this part of the data.

```
"main":{"temp":289.42,"pressure":1008,"humidity":55,"temp_min":287.15,"temp_max":291.15}
```

So I would like to create a class something like the below

```
class weather
{ 
var temp,pressure,humidity,..
}
```

Could someone please advise how I can use the DeserializeObject here?

Comment: Where are you getting the JSON from, are you reading it from a file? Getting it from a web request? Is this in the context of a WebApi or MVC application, or just a one off?

Answer (score 1):

Use json.net. http://www.newtonsoft.com/

Here is how to deserialize only the part that you need. Basically the class needs to contains the only the properties that you want to use and they must match the json vars.

```
var definition = new { temp = "" };

var weatherReport = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(yourString, definition);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one providing the service which returns the quoted JSON response I would strongly recommend that you edit the response to provide you with only the required data. This would not only reduce the data/time per request but would make processing it on the client much more efficient. However, if that is not an option I believe you can use [this link](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size) to get some idea about getting specific values of the JSON response as required.

However, the other option is to simply deserialize the entire object and get the required data since the performance difference between getting a specific part vs the entire object is not significant unless the JSON is significantly large.